# Would transferring an M.2 SSD between computers cause problems if it has Windows on it?

Tags: windows

Would moving an M.2 SSD with Windows used by computer A and files I want to copy to computer B (with its own Windows installation) cause any problems for Windows on computer A?

Edit - Sorry for lack of clarity but I only want to transfer files and put the m2 back in computer a

Comment: If you try to run Windows on Computer B (just moved the drive over), you will have driver issues. If it runs and then you start up Computer A you will have licensing issues.

Comment: Do you only want to access files on the drive? Or do you want to the Windows installation to boot on computer B?

Comment: You could use an M.2 drive caddy to connect the drive via USB. Drive A would probably end up with extra ACL entries from having to grant permission to access the files, but I don't know for sure, hence this only being a comment.

Comment: Hopefully the edit clears up that I just want to copy files and this would be faster than slow internet

Comment: I am not sure what part Internet plays, but if the two computers are not near each other, then you cannot use the same license on both computers  (which is as posted).

Comment: I want to copy files from one to the other and taking the m2 directly from A and putting it into B copying files and putting it back would be faster than an internet transfer. I don't, however, know if windows has file encryption or if the windows installation will be damaged by this process

Comment: Use a large USB drive instead. That will work better and eliminate Internet file transfer.

Comment: @RobertLucas This sounds like an excellent opportunity to start creating backups for the computers. All disk drives will fail at some time, so it is a good idea to have an independent copy of any data that you want to keep. Using Windows File History to save data to an external HDD is one way of doing that - more sophisticated backup methods are available.

Answer (score 0):

> Would moving an M.2 SSD with Windows used by computer A ..... cause
> any problems for Windows on computer A?

Yes. You cannot use the same license (almost for sure OEM) twice or even move an OEM license.

Windows (OEM) is restricted to the computer it came on.

If you (less likely) have a Retail license, you can remove the license from one computer and install and activate on another computer.

You are restricted to one computer per license with OEM and Retail.

If you just want files from the A installation, start it, copy files to a USB drive, then deactivate Windows and use the SSD on another computer for whatever use.

If you are just copying files for convenience, again it is better to use a USB drive as the intermediary transport mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it will not cause any trouble.** However, you should make extra sure you don’t accidentally boot it, because Windows will otherwise install all the drivers etc for computer B. The license is also a problem, but only if Windows can connect to the internet.

If you have two M.2 slots in computer B, go for it! Keep in mind though that using both (or specific) M.2 slots may be subject to conditions, because the number of available PCIe lanes is very limited on most PCs. Check the motherboard manual for more information.